How to build old versions from source (2.78c)?
I have some old .blend files that I want to work with that need 2.79 or older (they use the old internal renderer). I don't want to mess up my main Flamenco compute nodes with an old version, and am not in a rush, so thought I would build it from source on a rPi 4.
I have the source cloned, and the v2.79c branch checked out.
install_deps.sh is causing me pain. I edited it to change the dependency on libopenjpeg-dev to libjpeg-dev, and now I am to:
 libglewmx-dev : Conflicts: libglew-dev but 2.1.0-4+b1 is to be installed

Does anyone have any insight as to how to get the right dependencies installed for such an old version?

You can of course download any previous Blender version right back to 1.0 here. The source code is also available from this page.

Is there a special reason why you want to build it on your own?

Is there a typo in the text? There is no release version 2.79c, is there? And title of the question mentions 2.78c.
